# Facebook Open Graph follow action provokes an error when uses Open Grahp Test User as a profile

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-test-users

I'm developing a web application in php that uses CURL calls to Facebook Open Graph with an authorization token.
I'm implementing calls to [follow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.follows) action and it runs fine with the test users profiles, but it provokes an error message when it uses Open Graph Test User as a profile.
The message is the following:

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Could not resolve object at URL 100004155724366.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

This happened using both the Open Graph Test User as the follower and as the followed.

I find information about this bug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204978172961378/), but it doesn't solve the problem.

I receive reject messages from Facebook when I send it to Review because the Open Graph Test User fails, despite I let them know about this issue.

Is there a way to execute this follow action via CURL, using Open Graph Test User without errors?

I very much appreciate your help. This thing is getting me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue as you did and filed a bug with Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1509327415958565

Facebook was able to reproduce this issue and are mentioning it appears to be a bug and assigned this task to the appropriate team.

**Edit:**

It turns out this behavior is by design when a test user is following a real user. FB recommends for testing to use 2 test users and let one test user follow the other test user.